# Retrieving phone geolocation when user tap NFC chip?

Tags: geolocation, gps, nfc

I am developing a software to remotely manage NFC tags - change their actions and track campaign performance such as:

- No. of taps on individual NFC chips
- date and time of taps on individual NFC chips
- location of NFC chips when tapped

When the user tap the NFC, they are directed to our server which then redirect the phone's browser to the designated destination set in the campaign.

I have completed all of the above except for the location one as it gives me the inaccurate location.

At the moment, I'm using the site http://ipinfodb.com + their API to get the phone ip address and supposedly location, but it's innacurate.

Another, more accurate approach would be to "get" the phone's location via the GPS but not sure how to approach this.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Probably an easier solution would be to get the data out of an analytics backend such as Google Analytics (relying on their accuracy ...) 
Otherwise you need to ask the user's permission - but that needs to be done on the web site acting as the redirection target, as otherwise you would break the flow.